# Python: Making Background Image with Turtles

Tags: python, background-image, turtle-graphics

I am trying to insert a .gif file as a background image in my turtle world for a separate turtle to travel on, but I can't get it to work. I'm new to python and any help would be great.

Here's the current code:

```
from turtle import * 
from Tkinter import *

def test():
    turtle.bgpic("warehouse1.gif")
    fd(100)
    goto(50, 100)
```

Comment: Adding the code you're having a problem with, and maybe whatever error messages you're getting, will make it easier for people here to help you.

Comment: Create a complete minimal example that reproduces the error and [edit] your question to include the code and the error that you get e.g., run `import turtle; turtle.bgpic('your.gif')` and report any errors.

Answer (score 2):

`from turtle import *` makes available all names in the `turtle` module so you could use bare `bgpic()` in this case:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from turtle import *

def test():
    speed(1) # set the slowest speed to see the turtle movements
    bgpic('warehouse1.gif')
    fd(100)
    goto(50, 100)
    mainloop()

test()
```

Note: In general you *should not* use wildcard imports (`*`) outside a Python interactive shell. See [Idioms and Anti-Idioms in Python](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/doanddont.html#from-module-import).